# Remove trailing spaces from each line in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Can anyone help me, how to remove the trailing white spaces from each line in a string in ruby.... For example:

```
str = "Hello everyone. \nHope you guys are doing good  \nstrange i can't remove this spaces"
```

I tried rstrip but its not working for me.... May be have to try gsub.... I want the answer to be in below wayy.

```
"Hello everyone.\nHope you guys are doing good\nstrange i can't remove this spaces"
```

Comment: rstrip strips spaces at the end of a string, not at the end of each line. You could probably use regular expressions to substitute before each `\n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str.split("\n").map(&:rstrip).join("\n")
```

Its probably doable with regex but I prefer this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21), which will modify the receiver:

```
str = "Hello everyone. \nHope you guys are doing good  \nstrange i can't remove this spaces"
str.gsub!(/\s\n/, "\n").inspect
#=> "Hello everyone.\nHope you guys are doing good \nstrange i can't remove this spaces"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one using `gsub`:

```
str.gsub(/\s+$/, '')
#=> "Hello everyone.\nHope you guys are doing good\nstrange i can't remove this spaces"
```

`/\s+$/` matches one or more spaces (`\s+`) right before a line break (`$`)

Answer (score 0):

Or like this

```
str.each_line.map(&:strip).join("\n")
#=> "Hello everyone.\nHope you guys are doing good\nstrange i can't remove this spaces"
```